# Display a running clock in terminal using bash without using loop

Tags: linux, bash

How to display a running clock in a linux terminal without using any for or while loop. Using these loops in scripts with 1 sec duration causes a significant load in the systems.

Comment: You seem to make two assumptions (1) loops with one second delay in them have a significant impact on the performance of your system and (2) there is some construct with essentially the same functionality as the loop but better performance. Neither assumption looks well founded.

Comment: I had about 6 scripts running, with just the loop in script. There was a 0.3 %  cpu usage per script. so around 2 % cpu usag. In loops we call the date command periodically.

Comment: With a `sleep 1` in each loop? Cannot reproduce this, everything sits flat at 0%.

Answer (score 10):

How about:

```
watch -n 1 date
```

Use watch to run a command periodically.

Comment: watch looks good, but I am unable to customize the screen properly in watch(like colors), thats why I ignored watch

Answer (score 2):

You can make a function which calls itself with a `sleep` :

```
#!/bin/bash

function showdate(){
   printf '\033[;H' # Move the cursor to the top of the screen
   date             # Print the date (change with the format you need for the clock)
   sleep 1          # Sleep (pause) for 1 second
   showdate         # Call itself
}

clear               # Clear the screen
showdate            # Call the function which will display the clock
```

If you execute this script it will run indefinitely until you hit `CTRL-C`

Comment: the recursiveness is probably not a good thing in this context. Each one starts a process, and one process per second adds up fast.

Answer (score 2):

This post is ancient, but for anyone still looking for this kind of thing:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf '\033[;H'
while true; do date; sleep 1; done
```

This version avoids recursion (and stack faults!) while accomplishing the goal.

(For the record - I do prefer the `watch` version, but since the OP did not like that solution, I offered an improvement on the other solution.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the date to the terminal window title and your terminal supports it, you can do

```
#! /bin/bash

while :
do
    printf '\033]0;%s\007' "$(date)"
    sleep 1
done &
```

and it won't affect any other terminal output.

Comment: Since you use Bash + printf you could use `%(…)T` instead of shell'ing out. E.g.: `while :; do printf '\033]0;%(%F %R.%S)T\007'; sleep 1; done`

Comment: @xebeche true if using bash >= 4.2